# Boolean Algebra with Demorgans Law

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I have to prove that:
**!(a(b + z(x + !a))) = !a + !b(!z + !x)**

I am assuming that I have to use DeMorgans Rule so this is as far as I'm getting with:
**!a + (!b!z + (!xa))**

I'm not sure where to go from here. More specifically I'm not sure how to get rid of the **a** in **(!xa)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  !(a(b + z(x + !a)))
= !(ab + azx + az!a)  [distribution]
= !(ab + azx)         [a./a = 0]  
= !(a.(b+zx))         [factoring]
= !a + !(b+zx)        [DeMorgan]
= !a + !b.!(zx)       [DeMorgan]
= !a + !b.(!z + !x)   [DeMorgan]
```

There are not many rules to learn in Boolean logic.
Get used to them : There is DeMorgan, factoring, things like a+/a.b = a+b, etc...